# Can't run groovy command or script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I am new in Jenkins. I wanted to execute a simple groovy command or script from jenkins to explore more on groovy. I have installed groovy and java both in my jenkins master.

Whenever I run either below simple command or script through jenkins job.

-println "Hello World" or
-groovy /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CheckJenkinsMachineStatus/Hello.groovy

I am getting below error

[CheckJenkinsMachineStatus] $ groovy /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CheckJenkinsMachineStatus/Hello.groovy
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "groovy" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CheckJenkinsMachineStatus"): error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)

Comment: Do you want to run a command in Jenkinsfile or you want to fork a process on a remote node and that process is a groovy script or some jar file?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly write your groovy code inside the Jenkins job configuration.
Alterntively you can also create a Jenkinsfile which contains your groovy code and load this file in your jenkins job. Please see below example which executes the groovy code.
![jenkins [image: Execute Groovy Code for Jenkins]